# Oreo only play default notification in FCM

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Everything fine in marshmallow and nougat when notification come but when i test my app in oreo notification come but its play defalut sound that have selected in my phone. i am testing 2-3 oreo phone but same result. here is my notification code

```
   private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.vb_grey)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.offic))
            // .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());


}
```

can any one tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oreo Notification sound setting on `Notification Builder` will not work. You need to create a `NotificationChannel` and need to set that on `NotificationManager` to get it work as follow

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+context.getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.offic);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
        "YOUR CHANNEL NAME",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

    AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
            .build();

    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, 
            context.getString(R.string.app_name),
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);


    mChannel.setDescription(msg);
    mChannel.enableLights(true);
    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
    mChannel.setSound(sound, attributes); // Here you set the sound


    if (mNotificationManager != null)
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}
```

If Notification channel was already being used it will not work for first time.you need to create a different channel and set sound to it to make it work. You can use following code to check and delete multiple channel created.

```
if (mNotificationManager != null) {
        List<NotificationChannel> channelList = mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannels();

        for (int i = 0; channelList != null && i < channelList.size(); i++) {
            mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelList.get(i).getId());
        }
    }
```

Comment: first time its not working but when i change channel id and name its working fine. can you tell me why?

Comment: Answer is been updated for the same, Please have a look. Hope that will be self-explanatory.